# How to render my home component in the app.js file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render my home component in the App.js like this: `export function App() { return ( < Home /> ) }`

but It does not display my content. Why is that?

I am not receiving any errors.

Comment: Did you import the home Component? please, give more context about the problem. Or did you return anything from the home component? Please show the home component code.

Comment: Try this way - https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-phoebe-ungk7k?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import and call the component like I have mentioned below,

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import Home from './Components/Home'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Home />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```